# Mono for Android WebClient Special characters

Tags: c#, android

I'm using Mono for Android (C#) and WebClient DownloadString to get source code of a HTML website, that uses special characters (č,š,ž). But when displaying the code, it shows � instead of the characters. Is there a way to show the correct characters?

Answer (score 1):

This code removes or replaces the special characters in the string ....

System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(..) in C#

Comment: The command WebUtility is not even recognized (Using MonoDevelop).